# First page (titlepage) on the right side in reading mode

Tags: hyperref, pdf

Hi I would like to generate pdf document in `book` class that opens in following style by default:

```
    [1]
[2] [3]
...
```

I can't find a correct solution - should I look more into [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package? For reference book by [Scott Lilly](http://scottlilly.com/learn-c-by-building-a-simple-rpg-index/):

[image]

Comment: That is determined by your pdf display software.

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn can I force it somehow to display it this way by default?

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: Sorry about the terseness/shortness of my question. I assumed that the nature of it is such that it doesn't require MWE. I'll update it asap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to my PDF manual this is the correct setting, although it doesn't leave a blank space for the missing page.  Note that it ignores the LaTeX page numbers.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{mwe}% MWE only
\usepackage[pdfpagelayout=TwoPageRight]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.99\textheight]{example-image}
\mainmatter
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this one works correctly with Sumatra PDF and partially in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.